# How do I filter using Odata from dynamic data nested in a list?

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, filter, odata

example of json file

```
{
    "ProjectName": "14010-00 General Expenses",
    "ClientName": "Whiting",
    "Created": "2015-06-26T21:06:17.721Z",
    "Data": {
      "function": "LIT",
      "tag": "1461",
      "rack": "1",
      "slot": "4",
      "channel": "1"
    }
},
{
    "ProjectName": "104021-00 CPF",
    "ClientName": "Bonanza Creek",
    "Created": "2015-06-26T21:03:20.732Z",
    "Data": {
      "tag": "200",
      "function": "FT",
      "basemodel": "FT-200",
      "shortdescription": ""
    }
}
```

and I want to filter based on the contents of Data however this varies widely between the different components. So the Component.cs file possesses

```
public class Component{
    public string ClientName{get; set;}
    public string ProjectName{get; set;}
    ...
    public IDictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }
}
```

The problem might be from the dictionary being composed of string,object instead of string,string yet most, if not all, of the data's values are strings anyway.

So a

```
~/component?$filter=ClientName eq 'Whitning'
```

will work; however, the query fails on

```
~/component?$filter=Data/function eq 'FT'
```

and gives the error response
    **"The parent value for a property access of a property 'function' is not a     single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value."** and trying

```
~/component?$filter=Data/any(d: d/function eq 'FT')
```

gives the error response
**"Could not find a property named 'function' on type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair_2OfString_Object'."**

*So how can I filter by objects inside the Data object which are dynamically created and not always present?*

Comment: I would suggest you use [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) use OData as data source and use linq query on your objects and this will automatically generate the applied filters in URL as output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Web API OData?  If yes, `Data` is only a container for dynamic property. It shouldn't be present in the payload. So your payload should be:

```
{
    "Id": "558dbec9940bc716801a95d4",
    "FacilityName": "Ray",
    "ProjectName": "14010-00 General Expenses",
    "ClientName": "Whiting",
    "ProjectNames": [],
    "Name": "IoList",
    "Created": "2015-06-26T21:06:17.721Z",
    "Updated": "2015-06-26T21:06:17.721Z",
    "function": "LIT",
    "tag": "1461",
    "rack": "1",
    "slot": "4",
    "channel": "1"
},{ ...
```

Comment: But is there no way for it to work with the data container still present?

Comment: the data container? do you mean the odata client?

Comment: No I mean the Data object that contains function, tag, rack, etc.

Comment: Ok. I think you can create an open complex type for "Data" property to meet your requirement.